# Understanding $this->functionName(); in PHP

Tags: php

I am slowly trying to understand object orientated PHP, I am still finding my way with **$this->**, but am at the point where unless it sticks to the areas I am familiar with I get a little lost.

I have this snippet of code from a project I am reviewing that I am trying to understand, I am just wondering if somebody could provide some minimal/basic code that would go around (on the top and on the bottom) the example in order to successfully run it:

```
if ($this->isValid())
{
  print "Valid";
}
```

Comment: it means exactly what it reads. you are accessing a variable or method from `this` class .. or if its an extender class this will also apply to the parent class.

Comment: `isValid()` will either return `true` or `false` and if it returns `true` the condition gets executed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement would be inside a method inside a class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $valid = true;

    public function isValid()
    {
        return $this->valid;
    }

    public function MyMethod()
    {
        if ($this->isValid())
        {
            print "valid";
        }
    }
}

$myObj = new MyClass();
$myObj->MyMethod(); // prints "valid"
$myObj->valid = false;
$myObj->MyMethod(); // doesn't print "valid"
```

The `$this` variable refers to the instance of the object that a method has been called on.

Comment: Thank you @Carson-Myers, but since the code I am looking at is quite large and across many files I am wondering if you could add the isValid() function declaration into this as well - I am a little confused about how exactly it would have to look at a bare minimum in this example.

Comment: I mismatched $valid and isValid() accidentally when I first wrote it. I added isValid() now

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this` to refer to the current object.   In other words, use`$this->`  for non-static members and `isValid()` in method in class

```
class SimpleClass
{

    public $var = 'a default value';
             ^ 
             | refers variable   
             |
        $this->var; 

    public function isValid(){}
             ^ 
             | refers method 
             |
        $this->Isvalid(); 
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$this` keyword is used to access the current instance of that class and  `isValid()` is a function of that class.